Did any country in the G20 not condemn the Iranian drone & missile attack on Israel?
CNN:

In a joint statement released after the virtual meeting, the G7 members condemned “in the strongest terms” Iran’s “direct and unprecedented attack” against Israel and expressed their “full solidarity and support to Israel and its people and reaffirm our commitment towards its security.”
“With its actions, Iran has further stepped toward the destabilization of the region and risks provoking an uncontrollable regional escalation. This must be avoided,” the G7 statement said.

What about the longer list of G20 countries though? Did any of them not condemn the attack by Iran, or even explicitly accepted Iran's claim it was a valid self-defense move to the Israeli strike on their consulate/embassy in Damascus? (The positions of Russia and China on this would be most interesting, of course. There seems to be an ongoing UNSC meeting on this as well.)

N.B. I'm still interested in the wider G20: Turkey, Brazil, India, Indonesia, Mexico, Saudi Arabia, South Africa, etc.

China and Russia have called for restraint but neither condemned the attack.  Russia repeated the Iranian claim of self defense in their statement but didn't comment on its validity either way. China and Russia both condemned the April 1st Israeli airstrikes in Damascus.
China's response:

China expresses deep concern over the current escalation and calls on relevant parties to exercise calm and restraint to prevent further escalations. The ongoing situation is the latest spillover of the Gaza conflict. There should be no more delays in implementing UN Security Council Resolution 2728 and the conflict must end now.  China calls on the international community, especially countries with influence, to play a constructive role for the peace and stability of the region.

Russia's Response:

In the early hours of April 14, a large number of missiles and drones were launched at the territory of Israel. According to the Iranian Foreign Ministry, this attack was undertaken as part of the right to self-defence stipulated in Article 51 of the UN Charter in response to the attacks on Iranian targets in the region, including the strike on the consular section of the Iranian Embassy in Damascus on April 1, which our country strongly denounced. Unfortunately, due to the position adopted by its Western members, the Security Council was unable to provide a proper response to the strike on the Iranian consular mission.
We express our extreme concern at yet another dangerous escalation in the region. We have repeatedly warned that the numerous unresolved crises in the Middle East, primarily in the area of the Palestinian-Israeli conflict, which are often fueled by irresponsible provocative actions, will exacerbate tensions. We call on all parties involved in the conflict to exercise restraint. We expect the regional states to resolve the existing problems through political and diplomatic means. We believe it is important for the constructively-minded international players to contribute to this effort.


Managed to find their live UNSC comments now  https://youtu.be/DKe0H-WIp_o?t=2843 (China's follows right after Russia's.)

An intersting addition (via Iranian press): '"please remind me, when did Israel condemn at least one of the Kiev regime's attacks on the Russian regions? You do not remember? Neither do I. On the contrary, I remember regular statements by Israeli officials supporting the actions of [Ukrainian President Volodymyr] Zelensky," Zakharova said on Telegram.'

AFAICT, Mexico also expressed only 'deep concern', which is a bit short of condemnation. (Statement similar to the Saudis'.)

“The government of Mexico expresses deep concern over Iran’s attack against Israeli territory, and the impact that this could have on thousands of human lives. Mexico condemns the use of force in international relations, and calls on the parties to self-restrain and seek solutions peacefully to avoid a more general conflict in the Middle East. Mexico also emphasizes the importance of respecting international law for the sake of international peace and security.”

Also India's reaction was in the "seriously concerned" register:

"We are seriously concerned at the escalation of hostilities between Israel and Iran which threatens the peace and security in the region," the Ministry of External Affairs (MEA) said.
"We call for immediate de-escalation, exercise of restraint, stepping back from violence and return to the path of diplomacy," it said.

So, unsurprisingly, Indonesia's statement was pretty similar in the 'deep concern', but also took a familiar line against Israel:

Indonesia’s foreign ministry said it was “deeply concerned” and called on the UN Security Council “to act immediately to de-escalate tensions and continue working towards lasting peace in the Middle East, including by ending the illegal occupation of Palestine and various violations of international law by Israel”.


Regional G-20 members urged restraint, which in diplomatic speak is a mild statement and different from condemnation

Turkish Foreign Minister Hakan Fidan had a phone call with Iranian counterpart Hossein Amirabdollahian, diplomatic sources told journalists. Fidan stated that Ankara did not want any further escalation in the region after Iran's retaliatory attack against Israel on Saturday night. Source: Middle East Eye


Saudi Arabia said it was deeply concerned and called for the “highest levels of self-restraint,” according to a foreign ministry statement Sunday. Source: Washington Post


According to Deutsche Welle:

Responses from the Middle East
The Saudi Foreign Ministry expressed its concern at the "military escalation" and called on "all parties to exercise utmost restraint and spare the region and its peoples from the dangers of war." It said the UN Security Council needed "to assume its responsibility towards maintaining international peace and security."
Egypt's Foreign Ministry expressed "deep concern" at the escalation of hostilities and "maximum restraint" was required. The ministry's statement also warned of the "risk of the regional expansion of the conflict. Egypt would be "in direct contact with all parties to the conflict to try and contain the situation," the statement said.

Remark:  Egypt is currently not a G20 member, but a Permanent Guest Invitee.
